# Threading - make sure the thread finishes

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, thread-safety

SOLVED: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431782(v=VS.92).aspx

I have the following class that will give me the current location in WP7:

```
public class Position
{
    private GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = null;
    public GeoCoordinate CurrentLocation { get; set; }

    public Position()
    {
        ObtainCurrentLocation();
    }

    private void ObtainCurrentLocation()
    {
        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
        watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
        watcher.Start();
    }

    void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        //stop & clean up, we don't need it anymore
        watcher.Stop();
        watcher.Dispose();
        watcher = null;

        CurrentLocation = e.Position.Location;
    }

}
```

I want to use it to get the location. So what I do is to instantiate it. How can I make sure that, when I call the CurrentLocation property, the location whould have been acquired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your Position class implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and raise [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) when the value of the CurrentLocation property has changed.

Code that depends on CurrentLocation will then listen for Position.PropertyChanged and act appropriately when the event is raised.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I would highly recommend avoiding automatically getting the location on class instantiation. This complicates a lot of things. Second, I would recommend returning a `GeoCoordinate` through a method. Say you have a `public GeoCoordinate GetCoordinate()` that will return you the result - use it that way. This will make it a bit easier to get the data in a synchronous manner.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. Block waiting for `CurrentLocation` to be resolved. Not the greatest solution, UI might freeze etc
2. Implement a simple callback mechanism
3. Check for the status and leave (i.e. call it from wait loop of some sort)

Comment: Just an FYI, but frozen UI might be a reason for Marketplace disapproval.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431782(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score -1):

I am amazed that people don't know this stuff, the web abounds with tutorials and texts and this is one of the commoner topics.

Here's a good primer that's not too big: [Silverlight for Windows Phone - learn & practise](http://ebookee.org/download/?file=Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Edition%3a%20Programming%20Windows%20Phone%207)

And here, available from Microsoft Press at no charge, is Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows Phone 7](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/A/50A39509-D015-410F-A8F2-A5511E5A988D/Microsoft_Press_ebook_Programming_Windows_Phone_7_PDF.pdf)

Surprisingly, while the first book is a skinny thing in mangled English by some obscure Indonesian guy, it's easy to follow and it contains important stuff that's not in Petzold - such as how to use an InputScope, which is how you get that groovy list of suggested words while you type into a TextBox.

Comment: What can I say, Pete? I'm an idiot. Thank god we have guys like you to be amazed by our stupidity.

Comment: Just now I tried "location wp7" in Google and seven of the first ten links were what you require.

Comment: I told you: I'm an idiot. What else do you want from me? Go away!