# Threading - make sure the thread finishes in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

There is this thread with the same name but different purpose
[Threading - make sure the thread finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956960/threading-make-sure-the-thread-finishes)

This is a method that got attached to an event using the +=.

```
public void MsgBox(Int i, Int j)
{
     MessagBox.Show ("a");
     MessagBox.Show ("b"); //it was not MessageBox.Show ("b") in the original code.
     // It was something that is more time consuming for the computer
}
```

I will get MessageBox of value `a,a,a,b,b,b`

After doing some debugging, I realised before `MessageBox.Show("b")` can be called, the event invoke another MsgBox instance thus leading to `a,a,a,b,b,b`

Comment: Can you share the part where you create the threads?

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: notifiable.Onevent1 += (o, e) => { MsgBox(o.a,o.b); };

Comment: the output should be a,b,a,b,a,b

Comment: You want to control the order the events are called in?

Comment: May be ManualResetEvent..? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to have *syncronisation* between several threads, so that you get an output like

```
"ab ab ab"
```

Instead of

```
"aa ab bb" or "aa ba bb" or "ab aa bb" ...
```

For this you can add a common lock, so that all the threads attempt to acquire the same lock

```
// make sure there is only 1 instance of _obj shared between all threads
// one approach to do this would be to use a static object
private static object _obj = new object();

public void MsgBox(Int i, Int j)
{
    lock(_obj) 
    {
        MessagBox.Show ("a");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);   // simulate work
        MessagBox.Show ("b");
    }
}
```

Comment: may be u guess it correctly +1 while waiting for the OP correct his aswer

Comment: thanks this sound like a great idea but it don't work. I just tried it a min ago

Comment: it still produce the same result, a a a b b b

Comment: @user3398315 are you 100% sure there is a single instance of the locking object? Can you try `lock(typeof(MyClass))`? It must be the same type `MyClass` in all the threads (it's not a recommended approach but works for testing).

Comment: @oleksii I tried it and it the same. a a a b b b. I debug and the program keep returning to the start of the method

Comment: @user3398315 it's fine for the program to hit the start of the method, but not inside the lock, what happens if you set a breakpoint inside the lock method? There must be only 1 thread at a time inside the `lock{...}`.

Comment: it will keep jumping to the line after lock{}

Comment: @user3398315 it will only do that, if there are multiple instances of the locking object, can you pls post your locking code and the definition of the locking object?

Answer (score 0):

`MessagBox.Show ("a");` is a blocking code that will wait for user interaction  while others thread are doing  the some thing. so use a `Console`  application  instead to understand how threads works.

Comment: I tried removing MessageBox.Show ("a") and MessageBox.Show ("b") and tried running through the code. Still the same result, before the thread managed to finish, the compiler start a new thread

Comment: @KB you mean this? notifiable.Onevent1 += (o, e) => { MsgBox(o.a,o.b); }; . Sorry I am a novice programmer and this is not my code

Comment: Ok may be the best thing to  do  is try separately to  understand threads  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx and    messagebox http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx